# Keys & Buttons compatibiliy Java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, key-bindings

I have made my own version of Tetris in Java and i have added the possibility of moving the shapes both with JButtons and with certain keyboard keys. The code snippet i used is the following:

```
    leftButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent E) {

            moveLeft();

        }
    });

    rightButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent E) {

            moveRight();

        }
    });

    rotateButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent E) {


            rotateMovingShape();

        }

    });


    myPanel.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){


        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
                int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
                if (keyCode == event.VK_A)
                {
                  moveLeft();

                }
                if (keyCode == event.VK_D)
                {
                   moveRight();
                }
                if (keyCode == event.VK_S)
                {
                    rotateMovingShape();
                }
            }



    });
```

The problem i have is that after i use the JButtons, i cannot longer control the shapes with the keyboard keys. I suspect it has something to do with gaining/losing focus, but i am not sure. Could anyone tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

You get that problem, because you use `KeyListener`, instead of that you need to use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). For example:

```
    component.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A,0), "aPressed");
    component.getActionMap().put("aPressed", new AbstractAction() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("a key");
        }
    });
    component.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D,0), "dPressed");
    component.getActionMap().put("dPressed", new AbstractAction() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("d key");
        }
    });
    // other bindings
```

where `component` is your `JPanel`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately i do not know the majority of methods you wrote there. Can you direct me to a website or online tutorial from which i can learn them? I tried to look at the oracle tutorials but they are rather confusing.

Comment: may be javadoc help you with methods: [`getActionMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getActionMap()), [`getInputMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getInputMap()),[`getKeyStroke`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke(char)). Code in example just binds key to action

Answer (score 0):

A KeyListener only receives key events when the component has the keyboard focus. Clicking on the buttons transfers the focus to them and away from your panel, so you don't get the events. Any one of the following approaches will solve this:

- Call `setFocusable(false);` on the buttons so that they won't steal the focus.
- Add the KeyListener to the buttons too.
- Use [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead of a KeyListener, so that you can catch the key press whether the component has focus or not.